# Почему не работает функция смены изображения (Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

Я хочу, чтоб при нажатии кнопки менялось изображение. Однако функция use_e не работает. Причем она не просто не работает - она вообще никакие задачи не выполняет, в том числе и простейшие (вроде print)

```py
class RotationInfo(FloatLayout):

    aa_1_char = ObjectProperty()
    hold_1_char = ObjectProperty()
    e_1_char = ObjectProperty()
    q_1_char = ObjectProperty()
    aa_2_char = ObjectProperty()
    hold_2_char = ObjectProperty()
    e_2_char = ObjectProperty()
    q_2_char = ObjectProperty()
    
    save_icons_button = ObjectProperty()

    skill_1 = ObjectProperty()
    
    def use_e_1(self):
        self.skill_1.source = aa_icon_1 # глобальная переменная с адресом изображения

    def save_icons(self):

        self.aa_1_char.background_normal = aa_icon_2
        self.hold_1_char.background_normal = hold_icon_2
        self.e_1_char.background_normal = e_icon_2
        self.q_1_char.background_normal = q_icon_2
        self.aa_2_char.background_normal = aa_icon_1
        self.hold_2_char.background_normal = hold_icon_1
        self.e_2_char.background_normal = e_icon_1
        self.q_2_char.background_normal = q_icon_1

        self.save_icons_button.background_color = (0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.save_icons_button.text = ''
```

Мой `.kv` файл

```
<RotationInfo>:

    aa_1_char: aa_1_char
    hold_1_char: hold_1_char
    e_1_char: e_1_char
    q_1_char: q_1_char

    aa_2_char: aa_2_char
    hold_2_char: hold_2_char
    e_2_char: e_2_char
    q_2_char: q_2_char

    save_icons_button: save_icons_button

    skill_1: skill_1


    Button:
        id: save_icons_button
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.05
        text: 'Начать расчет'
        pos: 810, 400
        font_name: 'S:\GI-Roster\Genshin_Impact.ttf'
        on_press:
            root.save_icons()



    Button:
        id: hold_1_char
        pos: 350, 200
        size_hint: 0.08, 0.15
        background_normal: 'aa_defolt.png'
        on_press:
            root.use_hold_2
    Button:
        id: aa_1_char
        pos: 350, 300
        size_hint: 0.08, 0.15
        background_normal: 'aa_defolt.png'
        on_press:
            root.use_aa_2
    Button:
        id: q_1_char
        pos: 450, 200
        size_hint: 0.08, 0.15
        background_normal: 'q_defolt.png'
        on_press:
            root.use_q_2
    Button:
        id: e_1_char
        pos: 450, 300
        size_hint: 0.08, 0.15
        background_normal: 'e_defolt.png'
        on_press:
            root.use_e_2
    Button:
        id: aa_2_char
        pos: 625, 300
        size_hint: 0.08, 0.15
        background_normal: 'aa_defolt.png'
    Button:
        id: hold_2_char
        pos: 625, 200
        size_hint: 0.08, 0.15
        background_normal: 'aa_defolt.png'
        on_press:
            root.use_hold_1
    Button:
        id: e_2_char
        pos: 725, 300
        size_hint: 0.08, 0.15
        background_normal: 'e_defolt.png'
        on_press:
            root.use_e_1
    Button:
        id: q_2_char
        pos: 725, 200
        size_hint: 0.08, 0.15
        background_normal: 'q_defolt.png'
        on_press:
            root.use_q_1

    Image:
        id: skill_1
        source: 'skill_yacheyka.png'
        pos: -225, 450
```